# Does submitblock require the wallets private key?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward

I would like to know if invoking the submitblock RPC is supposed to work if the daemon that handles the RPC does not have the private-keys for to the coinbase output address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`submitblock` is not a wallet RPC so it does not need private keys nor is it related to anything in the wallet. It can be used even if the wallet is disabled.

Comment: So submitting a block to a node on behalf of your "real" wallet controlled by another node is a supported use case?

Comment: Yes. Block's aren't tied to wallets... You don't need a wallet to create a block, and a block does not need to be created by a wallet.

Comment: I ran into this issue https://github.com/vergecurrency/VERGE/issues/646 but hey that's VERGE /sigh